# PHP regex to catch currency and number together

Tags: php, regex

I am new to coding.

There is a problem to get the numbers from a sentence. I tried to find but unfortunately found nothing at all.

for example:
`usd5 for potatoes.` -> i want to catch "usd5" with php

How can I do this?

Comment: what exactly do you need to match? Every word containing a digit?

Comment: randomly i want to catch from in every sentence. usd5 or gbp4, it will find and return gbp5 or usd4 in a sentence

Comment: i think its easy but i cant find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.u will get the result as an array

```
<?php

$str = 'usd5 for potatoes';

preg_match('/(?P<name>\w+)(?P<digit>\d+)/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

u will get currency from $matches['name'] and value from $matches['digit']

Comment: its working as i need. thanks . what if i write "usd 5", not usd5.?

Comment: put a space between (?P<name>\w+) & (?P<digit>\d+)

Comment: (?P<name>\w+)single space(?P<digit>\d+)

Comment: okay, very thanks. lastly, how can i change order for ex. usb5 and 5usd for two possiblities what do i write??

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$str = 'usd5 for potatoes.';
$regex = '/(usd|gbp)\d/';
preg_match($regex, $str, $match);
var_dump($match);
```

This website offers an excellent introduction to regular expressions

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html